# UI-Bootstrap Popover goes off the screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using the Ui-bootstrap popover from **UI Bootstrap** (AngularJS).

and the popover in the border of the page seems to get out of the screen...

Is there a better way to position the popover - so it could stay inside the screen?

as you can see popover is cut...

[image]

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    content: 'Hello, World!',
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Title'
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
      <h4>Dynamic</h4>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Popup Text:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.content" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Popup Title:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Popup Template:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button uib-popover="{{dynamicPopover.content}}" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>

      <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Popup Title:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </script>
      <hr />
      <h4>Positional</h4>
      <button popover-placement="top" uib-popover="On the Top!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Top</button>
      <button popover-placement="left" uib-popover="On the Left!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
      <button popover-placement="right" uib-popover="On the Right!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
      <button popover-placement="bottom" uib-popover="On the Bottom!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Bottom</button>

      <hr />
      <h4>Triggers</h4>
      <p>
        <button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
      </p>
      <input type="text" value="Click me!" uib-popover="I appeared on focus! Click away and I'll vanish..."  popover-trigger="focus" class="form-control">

      <hr />
      <h4>Other</h4>
      <button popover-animation="true" uib-popover="I fade in and out!" type="button" class="btn btn-default">fading</button>
      <button uib-popover="I have a title!" popover-title="The title." type="button" class="btn btn-default">title</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QQxfc4BlHceJwt8zulKu?p=preview

Comment: Without seeing all of your code in a plunkr it's hard to know for sure what you've attempted.  You can specifically choose left, right, top, bottom etc.  If you have a control near the right side of the page, perhaps making it a 'left' popover makes more sense.  That said, it looks like a 'smart' positioning is something that is in the works.  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4762

Comment: Hi, 
I have aded a this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QQxfc4BlHceJwt8zulKu?p=preview

As you can see on the Top, Mouseenter and fading popovers the text gets out of the screen...

thanks for your help

Comment: Hrm.  Unfortunately, you may be out of luck unless you roll your own version of how it renders.  That said, It looks like the AngularUI folks have merged in an auto positioning feature as of 2 hours ago.  That said, it probably wont be part of the release until they oficially cut 1.0 https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/4899

Answer (score 2):

As others have said in the comments, UI Bootstrap doesn't support auto-positioning popovers, and it seems unlikely that they will in the future.

That said, you *could* do any of the following to help:

1. Make sure you're using containers, rows, and columns... this will give you the "correct" padding in Boostrap, which will help make sure (though not guarantee) that popovers don't go off screen.
2. If your element is positioned on the left, always put the tooltip to the right. Again, this should help, but no guarantees.
3. Use a fork of UI Bootstrap that supports ***Bootstrap 4***, which has much better auto-positioning for popovers (among other improvements). [Here's one option](https://github.com/Morgul/ui-bootstrap4) that seems decently maintained.

Comment: tooltip-placement did the trick, `top-left` and `top-right` opitons will come in handy considering the default value is `top` - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip